# runOnUiThread in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to convert an Activity to fragment. The error mark on `runOnUiThread`.
on the past:

> GoogleActivityV2 extends from Activity. runOnUiThread in class
>   ExecuteTask. class ExecuteTask nested on activity.

(Run ok)
now        :

> GoogleActivityV2 extends from Fragment. runOnUiThread in class
>   ExecuteTask. class ExecuteTask nested on activity.   (Error on
>   runOnUiThread)

here is my code

```
public class GoogleActivityV2 extends SherlockMapFragment implements OnMapClickListener , OnMapLongClickListener , OnCameraChangeListener , TextWatcher {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_googlev2, container, false);
        Init();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0){
        llLoc = arg0;
        stCommand = "onTouchEvent";
        lp = new ExecuteTask();
        lp.execute();
    }

    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(stCommand.compareTo("AutoCompleteTextView") != 0) {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading ..."));
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String ... args){
            do something
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            if(stCommand.compareTo("AutoCompleteTextView") != 0) pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    do something
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

the error says:
[image: Eclipse Error]

how can I fix this error?

Comment: The code you write inside onPostExecute already run inside main thread. On the other hands, you don't need to invoce runOnUiThread().

Comment: @rciovati "do something" in and out onPostExecute are different

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Try this: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable...`

It's because:

1) the implicit `this` in your call to `runOnUiThread` is referring to AsyncTask, not your fragment.

2) [`Fragment` doesn't have runOnUiThread.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/Fragment.java?av=f)

[However, `Activity` does.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java?av=f#4640)

Note that `Activity` just executes the `Runnable` if you're already on the main thread, otherwise it uses a `Handler`. [You can implement a `Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your fragment if you don't want to worry about the context of `this`, it's actually very easy:

```
// A class instance
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// anywhere else in your code
mHandler.post(<your runnable>);
// ^ this will always be run on the next run loop on the main thread.
```

EDIT: @rciovati is right, you are in `onPostExecute`, that's already on the main thread.

Comment: Some times getActivity().runOnUiThread is resulting into NullPointerException. Could you explain?

Comment: @developer1011 that will happen when the fragment has been detached from the activity. This is common in async tasks, because the activity could have been destroyed during the long running operation, so it no longer exists to `get`. Always check for null first.

Comment: Thanks. I surrounded ```getActivity().runOnUiThread``` with ```if (isAdded())``` and it works fine

Comment: @bclymer given this answer is the de facto reference on Google for UI thread in fragments, some more detail on the last section (how to implement a Handler that gets the same job done) would be nice!

Answer (score 16):

### Use a Kotlin extension function

```
fun Fragment?.runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
    this ?: return
    if (!isAdded) return // Fragment not attached to an Activity
    activity?.runOnUiThread(action)
}
```

Then, in any `Fragment` you can just call `runOnUiThread`. This keeps calls consistent across activities and fragments.

```
runOnUiThread {
    // Call your code here
}
```

> *NOTE*: If `Fragment` is no longer attached to an `Activity`, callback will not be called and no exception will be thrown

If you want to access this style from anywhere, you can add a common object and import the method:

```
object ThreadUtil {
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    fun runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            handler.post(action)
        } else {
            action.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I absolutely love kotlin extensions functions.

Comment: Is it not possible that the fragment is detached after the `(isAdded)` check but before `runOnUiThread()` dispatches the callback?

This will result in a NPE inside the callback.

Answer (score 12):

For Kotlin on fragment just do this

```
activity?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
        //on main thread
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

In Xamarin.Android

For Fragment:

```
this.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => { yourtextbox.Text="Hello"; });
```

For Activity:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => { yourtextbox.Text="Hello"; });
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

I used this for getting Date and Time in a fragment.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_head_screen, container, false);

    dateTextView =  root.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    hourTv = root.findViewById(R.id.hourView);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Calendario para obtener fecha & hora
                            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                            SimpleDateFormat date_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            SimpleDateFormat hour_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

                            String currentDate = date_sdf.format(currentTime);
                            String currentHour = hour_sdf.format(currentTime);

                            dateTextView.setText(currentDate);
                            hourTv.setText(currentHour);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.v("InterruptedException", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also post runnable using the view from any other thread. But be sure that the view is not null:

```
 tView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tView.setText("Success");
                    }
                });
```

According to the Documentation:

*"boolean post (Runnable action)
Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread."*

Answer (score 1):

This work with me perfectly in "android java":

```
 try {
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(requireView().getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```