# Fragment getActivity() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to do a simple task, that is to change a view Visibility after running a task, by calling the following code:

```
private void runTask(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            boolean status = task();
            setVisibility(boolean);  
        }
    }).start();
}

public void setVisibility(final boolean status) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (status) {
                    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Problem is: The task I run needs root (this works fine) and at this moment my Activity loses focus, so my Fragment is dettached and my `getActivity()` returns `null`. Even after the root command is executed, my Activity is brought to front but my Fragment isn't attached to it and isn't attached anymore

Also, I tried using

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

on my Fragment, and instead of calling `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`, I called `activity.runOnUiThread()` and this still doesn't work (the code runs fine, it goes into the if/else statement but nothing changes in the UI. I also tried calling `invalidate()` after setting the new visibility)

Any solutions?

Comment: `onAttach` is called when fragment is **first** attached to activity. It won't be called twice, I guess. Also, try to rephrase your question, it is not obvious what you do and what you want to achieve. For example, what do you mean by "root command"? Execute a task as a root user? Or else?

Comment: Yes, execute a task as a root user. And this isn't the problem as the command runs fine. I'm trying to update my view visibility according to the result of my root task, that returns a boolean and then I use it on the `setVisibility` method.

Comment: Why do you post a runnable to change view visibility? Your whole `setVisibility` code could be simplified to `myView.setVisibility( status ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);` Thus you will not experience your problem, as you will not need an Activity. It will be **far** more effective than creating and posting one new Runnable object to UI thread message queue.

Comment: Because I'm not in the UI Thread, I'm in a fragment in another Thread, therefore I cannot update views without running on the UI Thread. That's why the runOnUiThread, as seen at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425146/runonuithread-in-fragment

Comment: It seems like you lack understanding of the basic android concepts. When you do things **without explicitly declaring a new thread** (thread, asynctask, etc), you definitely are on the main thread of your application - UI thread. Calls to `myView.setVisibility()`, `myView.runOnUiThread()`, your `Runnable:run()` code - all get executed on the UI thread. It does not matter whether you're doing  it in Activity or in Fragment

Comment: **"...I'm in a fragment in another Thread..."** : Huh? Why is your `Fragment` running on another `Thread`? That makes no sense.

Comment: I'll update my answer, sec.

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1. Store the state of the flag. If the activity is attached, change it, otherwise store it. Set the visibility in the onResume method.
2. You might be able to use `View.post()`, much as you use `Activity.runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: Working on those atm.