# runOnUiThread() method in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I use `runOnUiThread` at fragment. And how to do it in fragment?

```
 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"any mesage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your requirement to run on ui thread , are you using any background task in your fragment because in a fragment you are in the ui thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425146/runonuithread-in-fragment Please see here it may help you.

Answer (score 8):

try

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"any mesage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `MainActivity.this`. Also use getApplicationContext() for the `Toast.makeText()` method

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"any mesage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```